# Newly added admin of realm can't login to the realm in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, redhat-sso

There are 2 realms in Keycloak: *master* and *custom*. Both have admin users.

Custom realm *admin* adds new user *new_admin* and assigns role *admin* to him via admin console.

The user can access his account details at `auth/realms/custom/account/`.

However, error `Forbidden You don't have access to the requested resource` pops  when *new_admin* user tries to enter realm administration console at `auth/admin/custom/console/`.

The same issue happens even when *master* realm admin adds new admin user to *custom* realm.

I'm using Keycloak 4.3.0.

Is it a bug or realm can't have two admins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to assign role `realm-admin` of `realm-management` client   to the second admin user.

[image]

Comment: I am accessing master console with admin. But I doen't find the  `realm-management` client. How can I turn it visible?

Answer (score 2):

You must explicitly assign the roles of "custom-realm" to the second admin user.
In admin console select the master-realm and go to "Role Mappings" of the second admin user. In the drop-box "Client Roles" select "custom-realm" and then assign the desired available roles to the user.

[image]

Comment: thanks, you helped me, however. I needed to add all roles of client named `realm-management`